# The number of polynomial functions $f:A\to A$ is $|A|^2$ if and only if $x^2=x$ for all $x\in A$.

Tags: functions, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, finite-rings

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $n$ elements, $n\ge2$. Prove that the next statements are equivalent:

1. $(\forall x\in A)(x^2=x)$.
2. The number of polynomial functions $f:A\to A$ is $n^2$.

I managed to do only the implication $a\implies b)$:

$f(x)=a_kx^k+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=(a_k+\cdots+a_1)x+a_0=bx+a_0$

$b$ and $a_0$ are arbitrary in $A$, so the number of polynomial functions is $n^2$.

Can somebody give me some ideas for $b)\implies a)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof of the implication $a)\implies b)$ is lacking; you prove that every polynomial function $f:\ A\ \longrightarrow\ A$ is of the form $f(x)=bx+a_0$ for some $b,a_0\in A$. This proves that there are *at most* $n^2$ polynomial functions $f:\ A\ \longrightarrow\ A$. You should show that they are all distinct.

For the converse; again show that the linear functions are all distinct. This yields $n^2$ distinct polynomial functions $f:\ A\ \longrightarrow\ A$ of the form $f(x)=bx+a_0$. So all polynomial functions are of this form. In particular ther exist $b,a_0\in A$ such that $x^2=bx+a_0$ for all $x\in A$. Plugging in $x=0$ and $x=1$ shows that $a_0=0$ and $b=1$, so $x^2=x$ for all $x\in A$.

---

Here's a more abstract alternative, that doesn't turn out to be any easier at all, but perhaps it offers another perspective:

Let $B:=\operatorname{Map}(A,A)$ denote the set of functions $f:\ A\ \longrightarrow\ A$. Note that $B$ is a group with respect to pointwise addition. Polynomials with coefficients in $A$ induce functions from $A$ to $A$ by evaluation, yielding a group homomorphism
$$\varepsilon:\ A[X]\ \longrightarrow\ B:\ f\ \longmapsto\ (x\ \mapsto\ f(x)).$$
Because $x^2=x$ for all $x\in A$ we see that $\langle X^2-X\rangle\in\ker\varepsilon$, and it is not hard to see that in fact the *ideal* $(X^2-X)\subset A[X]$ is contained in $\ker\varepsilon$. To see that $\ker\varepsilon=(X^2-X)$ it suffices to note that a linear polynomial $bX+a\in A[X]$ induces the zero map if and only if $a=b=0$; indeed from
$$\forall x\in A:\ bx+a=0,$$
it immediately follows that $a=0$ and $b=0$ by plugging in $x=0$ and $x=1$. Hence by the first isomorphism theorem the image of $\varepsilon$ is isomorphic to $A[X]/(X^2-X)$ which is a ring of $n^2$ elements.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: But if there are exactly $n^2$ linear polynomials, how do you know if there can be $x^2$?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

For b → a, consider the polynomial function $X \mapsto X^2$. It must be of the form $aX+b$, so...